# Mark a generated folder as resource directory in IntelliJ

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

### Question

Is there any way to get the syntax highlighting for resources that are copied at compile time?

I did try to mark the exploded resource folder as a resource directory in IntelliJ, but that did not change anything.

### More Info

So I have the following maven multimodule project:

- WebApp (war packaging)

  - src.main.webapp.view

    - index.html
- StaticSources (jar packaging)

  - src.main.resources.css

    - style.css
  - src.main.resources.javascript

    - test.js

WebApp depends on StaticResources and loads the css and javascript files with this setting:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <overlays>
                    <overlay>
                        <groupId>com.test</groupId>
                        <artifactId>StaticSources</artifactId>
                        <type>jar</type>
                    </overlay>
                </overlays>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

This results in the `target` folder looking like this:

- finalName (exploded folder)

  - css

    - style.css
  - javascript

    - test.js
  - view

    - index.html
- finalName.war (packaged war)
- war.work.com.test.StaticSources (The exploded folder of the copied resources)

  - css
  - javascript

### Problem

The outcome is exactly what I want, but I have one problem in the index.html.

When I link the stylesheet like in the following snippet, I get a warning (yellow highlighted text), because it doesnt find it in the current modules path, because it is only added at compile time.

```
<link href="../css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Comment: there is no way to resolve a file/folder that doesn't yet exist... And relative paths are always resolved relative to current file, regardless of the configured roots. So I can only suggest suppressing the inspection by adding `<!--suppress HtmlUnknownTarget -->` comment

Comment: @lena Thank you for your answer. Can you please provide it as an answer, so I can accept it in case no one else has anything to say to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to resolve a file/folder that doesn't yet exist... And relative paths (started with `./` or `../`) are always resolved relative to current file, regardless of the configured roots. 
So I can only suggest suppressing the inspection by adding `<!--suppress HtmlUnknownTarget -->` comment above the tag:

```
<!--suppress HtmlUnknownTarget -->
<link href="../css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```